# How can I use Json Jquery in api.openweathermap to get weather information

Tags: jquery, weather

I have this api

```
 http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Montpellier&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10
```

and I will get the information (name of city, weather...) using Jquery .

how I can do that ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an ajax call to get the JSON like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Montpellier&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10",function(result){
    alert("City: "+result.city.name);
    alert("Weather: "+ result.list[0].weather[0].description);
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cz7y852q/

---

If you do not want to use jQuery:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
              var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
              //access json properties here
              alert("Weather: "+ data.weather[0].description);
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400');
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=524901&APPID=7dba932c8f7027077d07d50dc20b4bf1", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Use your own [API key](http://openweathermap.org/appid) if the one in the URL does not work.

Comment: Yes , But how i can show for example the name of City and weather using this?

Answer (score 0):

Just issue ajax GET request:

```
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Montpellier&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10"

$.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

api.openweathermap.org implements CORS, which means that you will not have cross domain issues and can simply request API with AJAX.