# How to use Ajax and JSON to get weather info and put it into an HTML paragraph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

So I am having a problem learning how to use AJAX and JSON to retrieve weather information from [openweathermap](http://openweathermap.org/) and placing the information into a paragraph in an HTML page.

I found this piece of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336622/how-i-can-using-json-jquery-in-api-openweathermap-to-get-wheater-information) which briefly outlines what I need to do, but I don't want JavaScript alerts, and I can't seem to get it working.

My webpage currently looks like this:
[image]

And the code for that is here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>

function getWeather()
{
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=02878,us",function(result){
        var message = ("Weather: "+ result.weather[0].main);
        });
    });
}


document.write(getWeather().message);
</script>


<head>
<style>
firstDay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top:  100px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #8AC007;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 300px;
    height: 550px; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<firstDay> <center> <u> <h1> Today </center> </u> </h1>
<p> Weather here </p>

</firstDay>


</body>
</html>
```

**It would be awesome if you guys could show me how to get the result from the getWeather() function into the green box under the Today line.**

Comment: why document ready inside the function?

Comment: @Eric That's standard to make sure that the page is rendered and the elements are registered. Otherwise it could happen that the AJAX request finishes before the page is available to be interacted with

Comment: My issue was with the "inside" part of my statement. Also why use document.write if you are using jQuery?

Comment: @Eric Sorry you're correct about document.ready being inside the function - I wasn't looking carefully at it.

Comment: You should put the document.ready outside of the function not inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `append()` is your friend: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Instead of `document.write()`, just do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=02878,us",function(result){
        var message = ("Weather: "+ result.weather[0].main);
        $('firstDay h1').append(message);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I added your function to my code. The only issue is the weather is not being written. I don't think it's an issue with your code, rather could it be because I'm not calling that function anywhere within the HTML? I am very new to javascript and don't really know how to implement into HTML very well. Any help would be appreciated. (My code is the same as when I asked my question, I just replaced my getWeather function with yours)

Comment: You need to get jQuery first. Add `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` to your HTML code.

Comment: Additionally I wasn't thinking clearly last night - instead of defining the function, you can just have the anonymous function run on page load - I've updated my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is scoping. Move the `.write()` inside the callback:

```
var message = ("Weather: "+ result.weather[0].main);
document.write(message);
```

Once the Ajax callback returns asynchronously. That is when you have the data to write to the DOM.